# How can I sort my call history on Google Voice by call duration?

Tags: android-12, google-voice, google-pixel-6

I sometimes use Google Voice to make phone calls. How can I sort my call history on Google Voice by call duration? I recall I made a long phone call to a customer service and I'd like to see the phone number I called. Sorting by duration would allow me to easily get that phone number, as I don't remember when I made the call.

I use Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.